# How to open swagger-ui using docker

Tags: docker, swagger

I run this command from a local `swagger-ui` folder

```
sudo docker run -p 80:8080 swagger-ui-builder
```

Then I get these messages:

```
[20:37:59] Using gulpfile /build/gulpfile.js
[20:37:59] Starting 'connect'...
[20:37:59] Finished 'connect' after 19 ms
[20:37:59] Starting 'copy-local-specs'...
[20:37:59] Server started http://localhost:8080
[20:37:59] LiveReload started on port 35729
[20:37:59] Finished 'copy-local-specs' after 26 ms
[20:37:59] Starting 'watch'...
```

Then I open `localhost:8080` and see `Unable to connect` message instead of petstore demo project. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @JHarris: Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 0):

You need to use http://localhost instead of http://localhost:8080.

8080 is the port used by Swagger UI in the container but it's mapped on the port 80 in your system.